# Can intranet user play flash video? if they cannot connect to download.macromedia.com

Tags: video, flash, intranet

I use Dreamweaver CS3 to edit **intranet** pages, I insert the Flash Video , the Dreamweaver CS3 insert the codes for me.
I notice that the inserted codes has some internet address. I want to know assume my user cannot connect internet, can the play the video?

Assume their OS is Windows XP, has install Flash Player 7 or higher.

```
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0','width','600','height','340','id','FLVPlayer','src','FLVPlayer_Progressive','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_3&streamName=videos/GLD_01&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','FLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','FLVPlayer_Progressive' ); //end AC code
</script>
  <noscript>
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="600" height="340" id="FLVPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_3&streamName=videos/GLD_01&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
    <embed src="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_3&streamName=videos/GLD_01&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" quality="high" scale="noscale" width="600" height="340" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" />  
  </object>
  </noscript>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it'll work fine. The `codebase` and `pluginspage` parameters are not used if the plugin is installed, and are not used by current browsers even if the plugin isn't installed.

On some older browsers, they used to prompt the user to navigate to the referenced page to download the plugin, but newer browsers don't even do that.